# passing array parameters to path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to pass parameters to a path so that the path looks like the following:

```
http://localhost/submission_app/submissions?search_submission_type=ISH&submission_status_arr[]=51
```

I tried

```
submissions_path(:search_submission_type => "ISH", :submission_status_arr[] => 51 )
```

But am getting `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)` error message on my view page.

I then tried:

```
submissions_path("search_submission_type=ISH&submission_status_arr[]=51")
```

But this one gives me the following url (Note the dot instead of &amp before the argument)

```
http://localhost/submission_app/submissions.search_submission_type=ISH&submission_status_arr[]=51
```

How do I need to pass the parameters so that I get the correct format for the url?

Your suggestions are most appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Why do you need a post parameter that looks like `submission_status_arr[]=51`? Why does the page processing this require the brackets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails uses `parameter[]=value` to signify that `parameter` should be considered an array.

You just need to pass an array to the path helper to get rails to generate the path for you.

`submissions_path(:search_submission_type => "ISH", :submission_status_arr => [51] )`

Answer (score 3):

Correct syntax is

```
submissions_path(:search_submission_type => "ISH", :submission_status_arr => [51] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
submissions_path(:search_submission_type => "ISH", "submission_status_arr[]" => 51)
```